# Box.com API: How Do I Connect My Own Account To Upload Files?

Tags: php, rest, curl, box

I've a basic (free) account at box.com and I've build a form in PHP where user can select a file and pass that file to upload.php. Now, I need to connect to box.com servers and use my account to store that file. I have my own login used here.

How do I implement this?

Currently I'm doing this:

```
<pre><?php

$parent = array();
$parent['id'] = '0';
$params = array();
$params['name'] = 'Testfolder';
$params['parent'] = $parent;

$params = json_encode($params);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($params), Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=[api]&auth_token=[token]"));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);

?>
</pre>
```

But currently [token] is very very temporary and it isn't working as well. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.  I have had success using it and found it to be the best framework out there for box-api and php https://github.com/golchha21/BoxPHPAPI